# How do I deal with non deterministic value in SQLite3?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Below you can see the tables in my sqlite3 database:

- songs
- files
- tags
- playlists

These are the relationships between the tables:

- One To One: Songs and files
- Many To Many: Songs and tags, Songs and playlists

Below you can see the table queries I am using:

```
create_songs_table_query = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS songs (
                                song_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                title text NOT NULL,
                                artist text NOT NULL,
                                added_timestamp integer NOT NULL,
                                file_id INTEGER NULL,
                                FOREIGN KEY (file_id)
                                REFERENCES files (file_id)
                                ON DELETE CASCADE
                          ); """

create_files_table_query = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files (
                                        file_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                        filename text NULL,
                                        size integer NULL,
                                        song_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                        FOREIGN KEY (song_id)
                                        REFERENCES songs (song_id)
                                        ON DELETE CASCADE                                
                                ); """

create_tags_table_query = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tags (
                                 tag_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                 tag_text  text NOT NULL,
                                 tag_timestamp integer NULL,

                                ); """

create_songs_tags_table_query = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS songs_tags (
                                    song_tag_id  integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                    song_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                    tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                    FOREIGN KEY (song_id)
                                    REFERENCES songs (song_id)
                                    ON DELETE CASCADE,  
                                    FOREIGN KEY (tag_id)
                                    REFERENCES tags (tag_id)
                                    ON DELETE CASCADE  
                                    ); """

create_playlists_table_query = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playlists (
                                      playlist_id  integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                      playlist_title text NOT NULL,
                                      created_timestamp  INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                      updated_timestamp  INTEGER NULL,
                                    ); """

create_songs_playlists__table_query = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS songs_playlists (
                                            song_playlist_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                            song_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                            playlist_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                            FOREIGN KEY (song_id)
                                            REFERENCES songs (song_id)
                                            ON DELETE CASCADE,
                                            FOREIGN KEY (playlist_id)
                                            REFERENCES playlists (playlist_id)
                                            ON DELETE CASCADE  
                                        ); """
```

I am trying sucessfully to get the total songs each tag has and order by it:

```
SELECT tags.tag_id, tags.tag_text, COUNT(tags.tag_id) AS total, tags.included, tags.tag_timestamp 
FROM tags 
JOIN songs_tags ON tags.tag_id = songs_tags.tag_id 
GROUP BY songs_tags.tag_id 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

This is the query to order by tags.tag_text:

```
SELECT tags.tag_id, tags.tag_text, COUNT(tags.tag_id) AS total, tags.included, tags.tag_timestamp 
FROM tags 
JOIN songs_tags ON tags.tag_id = songs_tags.tag_id 
WHERE tags.included = 1
GROUP BY songs_tags.tag_id
ORDER BY tags.tag_text
```

I am using Python and Pycharm. Python doesn't return any records and Pycharm shows me the following pop up in the editor window:

```
Nondeterministic value: column tag_text is neither aggregated, nor mentioned in GROUP BY clause
```

Although, if I run the query from PyCharm's database console I get the desired results.

It's a bit tricky, any ideas ?

Comment: That doesn't look like an error message generated by sqlite, which is one of the few databases that actually allows for that sort of usage. https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html#aggregate_queries_can_contain_non_aggregate_result_columns_that_are_not_in_the_group_by_clause

Comment: There was a mistake in my Python code that didn't return the correct results. Although, this error might be more related to PyCharm that sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Writer the query correctly, so the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` columns are consistent:

```
SELECT t.tag_id, t.tag_text, COUNT(*) AS total, t.included, t.tag_timestamp 
FROM tags t JOIN
     songs_tags st
     ON t.tag_id = st.tag_id 
WHERE t.included = 1
GROUP BY t.tag_id, t.tag_text, t.included, t.tag_timestamp
ORDER BY t.tag_text;
```

This also introduced table alias so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: Are the additional fields in the GROUP BY necessary ?

Comment: @GiannisIordanou . . . If `tag_id` is unique in `tags`, then not strictly needed, but a good idea.